# I have an xml that i just created in my code and i want the same to be allowed to save using a dialog in Windows Forms C#

Tags: winforms, savefiledialog

```
stringXML = // My XML in string format.
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringXML);
```

Now this xmlDoc i have to save using a filedialog.. but i am unable to associate this with a save file dialog. any help / articles will help..

Comment: I got it... Thanks... !!

SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
s.ShowDialog();


xmlDoc.Save(s.FileName);

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution..

SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
s.ShowDialog();

xmlDoc.Save(s.FileName);

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above you may like to preserve the white space

```
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

before the save.

this would be for readability of the created document.